# Detect if Console/Command Line is waiting for user Input in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, input, process, command-line-interface

I am working on WPF and C# for creating IDE for my language called [EasyBite](https://github.com/Dangujba/EasyBite), i added a Output panel to IDE to display output of contacted Command Prompt using Process class, everything is working fine, until the program has an Input. It will terminate the execution once it reaches the input. If i am using the command prompt directly to run the program without the IDE everything is okay.

Please, How can i detect if the command prompt is waiting for input based on the running through the IDE like other IDE's used to do.

The logic is: I am passing the EasyBite interpreter  and file name as argument using the Process and here is the code:

```
private void StartEasyBiteProcess(string filePath, string compilerPath)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                
                OutputTextBox.AppendText("EasyBite Executing...\n\n");

                
                OutputTextBox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            });
            _easyBiteProcess = new Process();
            _easyBiteProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(compilerPath, "EasyBite.exe") ; 
            _easyBiteProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = filePath; // Pass the file path as a command-line argument
            _easyBiteProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            _easyBiteProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            _easyBiteProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            _easyBiteProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            _easyBiteProcess.OutputDataReceived += EasyBiteProcess_OutputDataReceived;
            _easyBiteProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            _easyBiteProcess.Exited += EasyBiteProcess_Exited;
            _easyBiteProcess.Start();

            _easyBiteProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
            foreach(ProcessThread thread in process.Threads)
    if (thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Wait
        && thread.WaitReason == ThreadWaitReason.UserRequest)
              _waitForInput = true;

        }
        private void EasyBiteProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                OutputTextBox.Text += "EasyBite program exited.\n";
                OutputTextBox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            });
        }
        private void EasyBiteProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                if (_waitForInput)
                {
                    OutputTextBox.IsReadOnly = false;
                    // Handle user input
                    HandleProgramInput(e.Data);
                    _waitForInput = false;  // Assuming that the input handling is synchronous and only for one line
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Read();
                    // Handle program output
                    OutputTextBox.AppendText("> " + e.Data + "\n");
                    OutputTextBox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                    OutputTextBox.CaretIndex = OutputTextBox.Text.Length;
                    OutputTextBox.ScrollToEnd(); // Scrolls to the end of the TextBox
                }
            });
        }

        private void HandleProgramInput(string userInput)
        {
            // Write user input to the standard input stream of EasyBite.exe
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = _easyBiteProcess.StandardInput)
            {
                if (streamWriter.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                {
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(userInput);
                }
            }

            OutputTextBox.AppendText("> " + userInput + "\n");
            OutputTextBox.CaretIndex = OutputTextBox.Text.Length;
            OutputTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
            // Scrolls to the end of the TextBox
        }
```

I found this here on Stackoverflow but not working

```
foreach(ProcessThread thread in process.Threads)
    if (thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Wait
        && thread.WaitReason == ThreadWaitReason.UserRequest)
```

I will appreciate if someone can help. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The `Console.KeyAvailable` property to check if a key is available for reading without blocking the execution of your program. This can be used to detect if the console/command line is waiting for user input.

Refer the working sample :

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue or 'Q' to quit.");

        
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable) // Check if a key is available without blocking the program
        {
            // Your main program logic goes here
            

            Console.WriteLine("Working...");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // Simulating some work
        }

        
        ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(); // If a key is pressed, read the key

        
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Q) // Check if the pressed key is 'Q' or 'q' to quit
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nQuitting...");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nContinuing...");
        }

    }
}
```

> **Refer the working sample [here](https://onlinegdb.com/alwofIDMv)**

Comment: I want to check through process class.  If am not working with the Console Directly.